# hide show multiple divs based on select with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have to write a simple script for a reservations form.
The idea is to show Number of Adults and Children inputs for each room selected.
But if number of Children is entered, I need to show Age Field, for each Children.

Like this :

```
 Number of Rooms - 2

    Room-1
    Adults: 2   Children: 2 
                Children Age[1] : 10 Children Age[2] : 15
--------------------------------------
    Room-2
    Adults: 2   Children: 1 
                Children Age[1] : 6 
--------------------------------------
```

That's the idea (like Expedia Seach Box).

Here is my code, is almost working. Bue whe I select Children Ages, the  With Adult and Children input disappears.

Here in my code:

```
enter code here

<lablel>ROOMS</lablel>
<select id="rooms" name="rooms" size="1"/>
<option val="">-?-</option>
<option val="1">1</option>
<option val="2">2</option>
<option val="3">3</option>
<option val="4">4</option>
<option val="5">5</option>
</select>
<div id="showRoom1" style="display:<?php echo $selhab1 ;?>">Room [1]
<label>ADULTS</lablel><lablel>CHILDREN</lablel>
<select required id="seldos" name="adlr1" size="1">
<option value="">--?--</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select id="child" name="chl" size="1" />
<option val="0">--</option>
<option val="1">1</option>
<option val="2">2</option>
<option val="3">3</option>
<option val="4">4</option>
<option val="5">5</option>
</select>
<div id="show1" style="display:<?php echo $seled1 ;?>">Age Child [1]
<?php       
echo'<select class="seldos" id=select name="age1" id="age1" >';
if($age1 == ''){
 echo'<option value="--">-?-</option>';
 }else{      
 print "<option value='$age1'>$edad1</option>";
 }      
 for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxage; $i++) {
    echo "<option value=$i>";
    echo "$i</option>";
 }
 print"</select></div>";
  ?> 
<div id="show2" style="display:<?php echo $seled2 ;?>">Age Child [2]
<?php
   echo'<select class="seldos" name="edad2" id="age2">';
   if($age2 == ''){
     echo'<option value="--">-?-</option>';
   }else{        
     print "<option value='$age2'>$age2 </option>";
} 
for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxage; $i++) {
    echo "<option value=$i>";
    echo "$i</option>";
    }
print"</select></div>";  
?>
   .
   .
   .
   ****  UNTIL CHILD AGE 5
</div>
```

```
<script>
$("#rooms").bind("change", function () {
var value = parseInt(this.value, 10);

$("div[id^='showRoom']").hide();

for(var i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
    $("#showRoom" + i).fadeIn(300);
}
});
$("#child").bind("change", function () {
var value = parseInt(this.value, 10);

$("div[id^='show']").hide();

for(var i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
    $("#show" + i).fadeIn(300);
}
});

</script>
```

Comment: I don't know what are you doing here. you are generating html for a select for same form. which is based on the AGE var. you know that i will be generated on next reload of page after form submit.

Comment: is it a multi-step form where your first ask for no of room. Then for no of Adults and no of children. And ask for age of each child in each room. i mean each step need to submit choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is this line:

```
$("div[id^='show']").hide();
```

This is hiding the `showRoom1 DIV` which contains the adult and children inputs.

Comment: No problem, if you feel this answer helped you, then feel free to accept this answer. You can also upvote answers that you like or find helpful.